# Spring-Boot Failing to @Schedule tasks for List of beans created by @Configuration class

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, javabeans, scheduler

I am attempting to create List of beans of the same type in a class annotated by @Configuration. What I need is to execute @Scheduled function declared in those beans.

```
 @SpringBootApplication
 @EnableScheduling
 public class DemoApplication
 {

     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
         SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
     }
 }


 @Configuration
 public class Config
 {
     @Bean
     public List<Monitoring> mon()
     {
         List<Monitoring> list = new ArrayList<>();
         for (int x = 0; x < 5; ++x)
         {
             list.add(new First());
         }
         return list;
     }
 }




 public class First implements Monitoring
 {
     private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(First.class);


     @Override
     public void doSth()
     {
         logger.info("first monitoring bean");
     }


     @Scheduled(fixedRate = 50)
     private void init()
     {
         logger.info("scheduled task");
     }
 }
```

What am I expecting from these code snippets is for my 5 Beans of Monitoring to print "scheduled task" every 50ms, but I never see this output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only creating a list as a bean with unmanaged `Monitoring` instances. That won't work.

You need to properly create the `Monitoring` beans (so that Spring can do its magic):

```
 @Configuration
 public class Config {

     @Bean
     public Monitoring first() {
         return new First();
     }

     @Bean
     public Monitoring second() {
         return new First();
     }

 }
```

Comment: Hi! Your answer does make sense to me, but my actual case requires reading a list of properties from .yml file. This is why I create a list of beans (one bean per property). If you were me how would you do this ?

Comment: In more dynamic scenarios I would schedule the tasks programmatically with `TaskScheduler`. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/TaskScheduler.html